# Tips/suggestions on creating a social app that has a Posts node on Firebase Realtime backend

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I just wanted to see if anyone can help suggest or give tips on how they have implemented a social app where users can 'post' on the app and users can see all the posts, much like 'Nextdoor' app.

I currently have the following setup on my Firebase Realtime database:

```
posts
----- <UID>
----------- <POSTID>
------------------- created
------------------- image
------------------- posttext
------------------- likes
------------------- <poster>
---------------------------- uid
---------------------------- username
```

So one of my questions is do I even need the 'posts' node!? This node would contain all the posts name by a user...

Should I just put in a 'timeline' node instead and remove the child node for  and make it look like this:

```
timeline
-------- <POSTID>
----------------- created
----------------- image
----------------- posttext
----------------- likes
----------------- <poster>
-------------------------- uid
-------------------------- username
```

this way i can query the 'timeline' node, which will also make it possible to have pagination by using the queryLimited(toLast: Int) in my firebase query?

What are your thoughts and/or do you have a better way to organize the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modeling data in a NoSQL database depends largely on the use-cases on your app. For that reason it's impossible to give data modeling advice outside of the context of a specific use-case.

For example: if your user all see the same timelines of all posts by all users, then it makes sense to store the data in that format in the database.

This is actually quite common in Firebase: you model the data that you see (in a part of the screen) pretty directly in the database.

That also means that, if you see the same data in multiple screens in your app, it is quite normal that this data also exists in multiple places in the database. Duplicating data is a common idiom in NoSQL database.

You'll want to consider these as you add use-cases to your app, as you'll frequently find yourself changing and augmenting your data model to allow for the new use-cases.

For a longer introduction I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: thank you for the rational for NOSQL , but on your take `same timelines of all posts by all users, then it makes sense to store the data in that format in the database` would you recommend the `timeline node or the second case` in my question? It would seem that my use case that does make more sense... what are your thoughts?